# Exposing API in polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to learn polymer, and I'm trying make a basic messaging framework. So I created a little polymer-element called messages-framework that will display messages, and after 3 seconds remove the message. How can expose a method that will add a message to this element?
Here's my polymer element

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input-decorator.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">   

<polymer-element name="messages-framework">                                     
  <template>                                                                    
    <ul>                                                                        
      <template repeat="{{ m in messages }}">                                   
       <li>{{ m }}</li>                                                         
      </template>                                                               
    </ul>                                                                       
    <paper-input-decorator label="message" floatinglabel>                       
      <input is="core-input" value="{{ message }}" type="text">                 
    </paper-input-decorator>                                                    
    <paper-button raised on-tap="{{ addMessage }}">Add Message</paper-button>   
  </template>                                                                   
  <script>                                                                      
    Polymer({                                                                   
      messages: [],                                                             
      addMessage: function () {                                                 
        this.messages = this.messages.concat(this.message);                     
        setTimeout(this.removeMsg.bind(this, this.message), 3000);              
        this.message = "";                                                      
      },                                                                        
      removeMsg: function (msg) {                                               
        this.messages = this.messages.filter(function (m) {                     
          return msg !== m;                                                     
        });                                                                     
      }                                                                         
    });                                                                         
  </script>                                                                     
</polymer-element>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

I don't think I phrased my question well. If have had two polymer elements, for instance messages-framework and a newuser-form, if newuser-form needed to add to the messages-framework, how would that polymer element use messages-framework API?

Answer (score 0):

Exposing API in Polymer is just like one would do in every day elements.

1. Get a reference to the Element. eg *var p = document.getElemnetTagName('p');*
2. use it's methods. eg *p.innerHTML = "Hello World"* or *p.setAttribute(attribute,value)*

Example:
Your Custom Element

```
<polymer-element name="messages-framework">                                     
  <template>                                                                    
    //all your core markup
  </template>                                                                   
  <script>                                                                      
    Polymer({                                                                   
      messages: [],                                                             
      addMessage: function () {                                                 
        this.messages = this.messages.concat(this.message);                     
        setTimeout(this.removeMsg.bind(this, this.message), 3000);              
        this.message = "";                                                      
      },                                                                        
      removeMsg: function (msg) {                                               
        this.messages = this.messages.filter(function (m) {                     
          return msg !== m;                                                     
        });                                                                     
      }                                                                         
    });                                                                         
  </script>                                                                     
</polymer-element>
```

Using it's API

```
<body>
  //Initialing the Element by loading it on to the page
  <messages-framework></messages-framework>

<script>
var messagesFramework = document.getElementsByTagName('messages-framework');

//this will call the addMessage() method of the element
messagesFramework.addMessage();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how this polymer/the shadow dom works well enough. And I may have not have phrased my question well enough.  It's my understanding that each polymer element create's its own DOM. Your answer would work well enough if I was on the outer dom element each time. But how would I use addMessages if I were in another polymer element?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an array, so you need to index into it: `var messages = document.getElementsByTagName('messages')[0]`.

Comment: This isn't valid anymore on >= Polymer 1.0, is it?